# GPU unavailable for openVINO when Intel Atom E3950 NUC is headless

Tags: headless, openvino

I have installed XRDP on Up2 board running Ubuntu 16.04 and my acceleration on the GPU works fine when I connect a monitor and run it locally. It also works fine when I run it remotely so long as a monitor is connected. Once the monitor is disconnected I get    self.exec_net =

self.ie.load_network(network=self.net,device_name=self.plugin)

File "ie_api.pyx", line 178, in

openvino.inference_engine.ie_api.IECore.load_network

File "ie_api.pyx", line 187, in

openvino.inference_engine.ie_api.IECore.load_network

RuntimeError: Failed to create plugin

/opt/intel/openvino_2020.3.194/deployment_tools/inference_engine/lib/intel64/libclDNNPlugin.so

for device GPU

Please, check your environment

[CLDNN ERROR]. clGetPlatformIDs error -1001

Is the GPU being disabled when no monitor is detected? if so, how can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

To load GPU plugin, Intel® Graphics Compute Runtime for OpenCL™ driver components are required to be installed.

In your scenario, GPU plugin is working fine when connecting to a monitor. This issue only happens when the monitor is not connected. Usually, the operating system detects a connected display (monitor) and enables the GPU. The GPU hardware is often disabled when no connected display is detected.

We recommend you post your question in [xrdp GitHub](https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues) for further advice to enable GPU without connecting to a monitor.

Comment: I appreciate the quick response and I will take this to xrdp github... However, since posting I purchased a display emulator fake plug https://www.amazon.com/dp/B074NNZYW4?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2_dt_b_product_details  and the issue did not go away as I was expecting. This tells me it is likely not a xrdp issue , would you agree?

Comment: I was able to use GPU plugin on my host machine. With this, it is not OpenVINO issue but more into XRDP compatibility/limitation as it works with SSH mechanisms.